# Validate Form in Meteor

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor, coffeescript, jquery-validate

I'm using the jQuery Validation Pugin, but i have an option to add new texts fields required , the first text field validates it, others did not.

HTML:

```
{{#each form}}
<input type="text" id="{{id}}" required>
{{/each}}
```

Add New Field:

```
Template.form.events
  'click #add': (e, t) ->
    data = Session.get('form')
    data.push
      id:  data.length + 1
    Session.set 'form', data
```

Rendered:

```
Template.form.rendered = ->
  $('form').validate()
  Session.set 'form', [
    id: 1
  ]
```

Helper:

```
Template.form.helpers
  form: ->
    Session.get 'form'
```

Comment: It would have been better to show the ***rendered*** HTML as seen in the browser source.  See:  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code here...

```
{{#each form}}
<input type="text" id="{{id}}" required>
{{/each}}
```

I don't see a `name` attribute as part of the `input` element.

For the jQuery Validate plugin to function properly, every input **must** have a unique `name` attribute.  It's how this plugin keeps track of every input.  This is exactly why you're only getting validation on the first input.

[See documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/reference/#markup-recommendations):

> *"The name attribute is "required" for input elements, **the validation plugin doesn't work without it**."*